# Accessing BigCommerce Logged In user from wordpress on subdomain

Tags: wordpress, bigcommerce

So I need a way to lock down both bigcommerce and wordpress if a user is not logged in. First suggestion was asking if when a user is created in bigcommerce create the same user account in WP... but that doesn't seem like a good approach to me since the user will not need any interaction as a user on WP just need to block access to pages if they are not logged in.

So my thought is to check if a user is logged into bigcommerce, then pass a variable to wp header file. If the variable does not exist then redirect them back to bigcommerce login. For this install BigCommerce is currently using the header from wp so they match and all works well so that is why I assume I should be able to pass a variable to check if a user is logged into bigcommerce or not. I have not been able to find any documentation in the API about accessing if a user is logged in or not.

Has anyone done anything like this and or know if this would be possible? Or know of a better solution for what I am trying to do. Maybe check for a cookie or session?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did a project where the client wanted to show custom content to bigcommerce loggedin users and block the rest. The best way I found was to check the value of %%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%. It is "Guest" for non-loggedin users. 
you can try this:

```
localStorage.setItem("user", %%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%% );
```

and then you can use on wordpress pages :

```
var  user =  localStorage.getItem("user");
if(user=="Guest"){
 //redirect to login or block page
}
```

Obviously they can get around javascript so using ajax to store it somewhere and then retrieving it would be more secure but I hope this will help you proceed :)

Comment: Where were you using locatStorage at? Were you using this in the bigcommerce header file? Once set its always going to exist on that users system though right? Thanks for the suggestion I will play around with it and update if it's going to work.

Comment: You can use localStorage in header file or anywhere in the template. It will work. Let me know if you run into trouble :)

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is going to work for me since it won't work across different sub domains etc. It worked on the main bigcommerce pages that was including the wp header, but then on the actual wp pages user was always null as it didnt have access to that localstorage since this seems to be domain specific. It also doesn't work on mobile devices.

Comment: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#customer-login-api is now an available option to use to achieve this